# Controls Wrong in Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10, my forms show wrong components, only the cursor appears in the fields.

Already changed background colors, fonts, and nothing.

Visual Studio 2013 Net Framework 4.5.

Windows 7:
[image: Windows 7 screenshot]
Windows 10:
[image: Windows 10 screenshot]

Comment: have you installed the framework redist on your new windows installation? Code rarely just "deletes" elements like this.

Comment: When I try to install it shows message that already exists

Comment: Is this an app in development, or current production.

Comment: Is appearance the only problem (e.g. buttons working? text can be entered?)? What *components* were used? Standard `TextBox` or e.g. some library? Is this the only one `Form` with the problem (it contains crystal report viewer, can it be a problem), other forms are ok?

Comment: All components are visual studio Standard. The functions of the buttons work.
Application in production , development use windows server 2008.

Comment: Is this only happening with this particular WinForms application? Does this only happen on your windows 10 installation? Because these things can also happen if there is a problem with some hardware drivers like a video card driver.

Comment: Its work! Video Driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 the video driver did not provide more compatibility. Updating the video driver to the compatible with Windows 10 , the error has been resolved !